# Questions for data loss in Flink

Tags: apache-flink

I am asking a few questions regarding data loss in Flink in certain scenarios.

**Configuration**

- checkpoint for fault tolerant
- Kafka for Source
- NoSql for Sink

Can data loss be happened for following cases?

1. Flink uses the async sink for latency. The requested messages for db are not correctly inserted but checkpoint is completed. It is possible because the sink is async so the requested messages from sink are going to db side and flink don't care of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this is not a problem.

Flink's generic async sink maintains a buffer storing everything written to the sink that hasn't yet been acknowledged. If the write to the external data store fails, it will sink will retry. And that buffer is checkpointed, so if the Flink job fails, that buffer will be restored.

This is described in [FLIP-171: Async Sink](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/FLINK/FLIP-171%3A+Async+Sink) and in a blog post about [The Generic Asynchronous Base Sink](https://flink.apache.org/2022/03/16/the-generic-asynchronous-base-sink/).